# How to convert DB2 string column with different formats of datetime to datetime?

Tags: varchar

I have a varchar column [DB_TIMESTAMP] in a (DB2) table which get data from different sources/environments, This column have different formats in it like:

```
11/15/2019 11:30:02

11/15/2019 11:22 AM

2019/11/15 11:15 AM
```

I have to put remarks using CASE in my query to find if there is any row that has 2 hours delay from current DateTime with this column data then mark them pending.
I tried like following, but it need the column with DateTime format which it is not because of different format of data entered in it:

```
CASE WHEN days (current date) - days(DB_TIMESTAMP))>2 
[for checking 2 hours difference]
```

I think, this column needs to be converted into DateTime then try with above may work, but how:

Please help.

Shamshad Ali

Answer (score 0):

Try Something May it helps:

```
CASE WHEN DAYS (Replace (CONVERT(nvarchar (500), CURRENT_DATE ,106),' ','-') as current_date)
         - DAYS(Replace (CONVERT(nvarchar (500), DB_TIMESTAMP ,106),' ','-') as DB_TIMESTAMP))>2
```

Comment: I'm using DB2 database in DB2, It won't work with CONVERT(varchar,, 106) <-- your solution is for SQL Server.